# Adding Module Mapping in IIS 8 to run python 3.6.3 web services asks for .exe or .dll extensions

Tags: python, django, mapping, fastcgi, iis-8

I am trying to run my python(3) web service using IIS 8 following the instruction provided [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html)
Everything is fine to the point where I try to add "FastCgi Module" in "Add Module Mapping" section. The problem is when I click on OK on "Add Module Mapping" window, the error pops up:

> The specified executable for the handler must be .dll or .exe file. If the path to the script processor (only in the case of a .exe file) has spaces, use " marks to specify the executable.

I suppose there has to be a FastCgi.dll?

Is there a better way to achieve that?

P.S: I have read an ample of instructions regarding running python 2.6 web services on IIS using ISAPI_WSGI Handler and there are warnings regarding using it on later python versions, I wonder if that instructions hold up using python 3.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add Executable setting, it must be an executable, this means that is has to be either .exe or .dll. If you look at the picture in the instructions, you will see an executable there (python.exe).

[image]

If you don't provide path to an executable, error that specified executable must be .dll or .exe will pop up. Make sure you are referring to an executable there and it should be fine then.

Comment: It says to enter the following:
C:\virtualenvs\foo\Scripts\python.exe|C:\virtualenvs\foo\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py
in executable box. is wfastcgi.py considered executable (despite the extension)? @Borut

Comment: No, `C:\virtualenvs\foo\Scripts\python.exe` is an executable, that executes `C:\virtualenvs\foo\Lib‌​\site-packages\wfast‌​cgi.py`

Comment: I see. The problem was I had to put each parameter inside " since I had a space in one of my paths. However I think your answers both to the question and in comment deserve to be seen as the right one. thanks. @Borut

Comment: I had to put both parameters in double quote saparated by bar "|" e.g. `"c:\python39\python.exe"|"c:\python39\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"`